# Читать файл из памяти телефона

Tags: android, uri, glide

Создаю файл с изображением с камеры таким образом

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFolder");

try {
    File imageFile = new File(direct, fileName);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

А как его читать? Т.е. мне нужно в imageView вывести картинку. Такой способ не работает

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myFolder" + fileName)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: А права на чтение есть? У приложухи есть доступ читать?

Comment: в манифесте добавил <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` используйте. Имя файла это не URI, не распарсится.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Сработало так

```
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myFolder" + "/" + fileName;

File file = new File(completePath);
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(imageUri)
        .into(imageView);
```